# Difference between 'Start' and 'Start no pauses' option in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

1. When should I execute my test using "Start" or "Start no pauses" option/button?
2. What is the advantage of "Start" over "Start no pauses" or vice-versa ?

[image: Start/Start no pauses]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*No pauses* means ignore timers, It's a [productivity feature](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter-new-gui-features-to-increase-your-productivity/)

> Thank’s to this feature, you’ve spared 15 seconds of scripting time. Multiply this with the number of times you run a Test during debug phase and you see how much time you can gain.